# Save dataframe in a folder which has sys.date

Tags: r, path, sysdatetime

How can I save a file in a specific folder which has `Sys.date()`?

`write.csv(dummy_opp, file = "//ant/dept-as/XYZ2-User/Mega_data/File Management/SOA/Assignment-(***This folder is appended by sys.date***)"Workbook.csv",row.names = FALSE)`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
date<-as.character(Sys.Date())
  write.csv(dummy_opp, file = paste0("//ant/dept-as/XYZ2-User/Mega_data/File Management/SOA/Assignment-",date,"/Workbook.csv"),row.names = FALSE)
```

`file` will be:

```
"//ant/dept-as/XYZ2-User/Mega_data/File Management/SOA/Assignment-2018-02-19/Workbook.csv"
```

Or, if you want a more compact code:

```
  write.csv(dummy_opp, file = paste0("//ant/dept-as/XYZ2-User/Mega_data/File Management/SOA/Assignment-",Sys.Date(),"/Workbook.csv"),row.names = FALSE)
```